# Instantiate a class collection member with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory, smart-pointers

I have a `Snake` class which is composed of several `SnakeCell`

```
struct SnakeCell
{
    SnakeCell(size_t x, size_t y) : origin_(x, y) {}

    std::pair<size_t, size_t> origin_;

};

class Snake
{
public:
    Snake(size_t x, size_t y ) : cells_({std::make_unique<SnakeCell>(x, y)}) {}


private:
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<SnakeCell>> cells_;

};
```

A `Snake` is initially created with one `SnakeCell`.

*Why using a pointer for snake cells?* 
Cells will often be modified, e.g. their x and y components. It make sense to modify them directly when it happens rather than creating a copy and reinitialising the entire `cells_` deque.

*Why using a unique_ptr* 
That's where I am not sure if it's the right kind of pointer to use. The original idea was to make sure that every cells are deleted from a memory perspective when the snake itself is deleted. From a design perspective, a `Snake` object would be the **only one** that manages its `cells` so it makes sense to use a `unique_ptr` rather than a `shared_ptr` but **I think this is where my understanding of smart pointers is incorrect.**

Anyway, the compiler complains when using unique_ptr

`Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<SnakeCell, std::__1::default_delete<SnakeCell> >'`

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You're right; there's no apparent reason to use pointers here.

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
cells_({std::make_unique<SnakeCell>(x, y)})
```

invokes this constructor

> ```
> deque( std::initializer_list<T> init, 
>        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```
>
> [from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque)

---

[`std::initializer_list<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) is a `const T[]` under the hood. `const` object cannot be moved - explaining the error you're getting.

Possible fix:

```
Snake(size_t x, size_t y) 
{
    cells_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<SnakeCell>(x, y));
}
```

*I hate `initializer_list`...*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But aren't `initializer_list` required to avoid unnecessary call to default constructors?

Comment: EDIT : Sorry, I've confused it with member initialisation list